# Asset Indexing breaking images

Tags: assets

My client hit the update asset indexing button in the settings panel and now the images are all appearing broken. Can you suggest how to fix this?

Example image:

https://cookproperty.co.nz/assets/uploads/_imageSlider/CookProperty__50I8095.jpg

Whats weird is when you hover on the link on the inspector is shows correctly?

[image: image working in inspector]

Any help would be much appreciated!

T

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/assets/uploads/16-hurstmere.jpeg" width="100%" title="" alt="">
```

you also appear to have an issue with opacity triggers on some of these sliders.
[image: image shows opacity issue]
https://cookproperty.co.nz/properties/retail

The primary issue here appears to be that the page is loading the placeholder, or the placeholder has overwritten the original file.

What you have in the Control Panel is the thumbnail of the image. Another image file will have been created and stored, but it looks like it's the placeholder/fallback version.

1. Check that you have the correct volume storage configured and there is space to write the files
2. Check that the permissions allow for volume creation, cause if you're rendering multiple image variations, then you will have issues with these not being properly structured.
3. Check that the job queues aren't failing partway through.
4. Check that the update hasn't changed the volume name as in placed it in archive and created a new one called uploads
5. Remove their access to settings when deploying to production. (If the site is configured correctly, the client shouldn't need to manually run queues.

Just a tip for future questions, post the code that is wrapping the probable source of the error. Both twig and HTML.

I'll have my mate jugs come to take a closer look at this for you.

On another note, we have a plugin that handles this problem for you and probably some other ones you're running into with the asset management and media rendering. It'll certainly speed up your page loads. It also lets you swap media types with one field, stand-alone or within a matrix. Think video, svgs, documents, socialposts, all managed from the one field.

Image optimisation:
https://oneplugin.co/optimised-images-for-craft-cms

Media types the plugin controls:
https://oneplugin.co/how-it-works

Feel free to hit us up here:
https://oneplugin.co/contact